# Determining whether each of a large number of values exists in another region of the spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet, where column A contains 371000 values, and the region D1:RO1048576 contains another set of values.

For each populated cell in column A, I would like to put into column B:

- A one if the value in column A exists in the big region
- A zero if it does not

How would I go about doing this, either in VBA or an Excel formula? I have tried to use VLOOKUP and INDEX/MATCH without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In B1:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($D$1:$RO$1048576,$A1),1,0)
```

Then copy down

Edit: Did not put realize that this was the entire column and your local settings:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($D:$RO;A1);1;0)
```

Comment: It didn't work.An error occured. :( my office is office 2010

Comment: @mahmutziya Are your local settings set for using `;` as delimiter instead of `,`?  Depending on your local settings you many need to change all the `,` to `;`.

Comment: its ok. But now a new error occured. Excel changed the formula to this =IF(COUNTIF($D:$RO;$A1);1;0)

Comment: @mahmutziya That should work, it is looking in the entire columns D to RO.

Comment: wooooooooooooooow. It has worked now. Than you so much Scott.

Comment: @mahmutziya glad I could help, please consider marking as correct.